# Why are parenthesis used in the middle of a method call in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, field, instance

I came across some code and cannot understand a certain aspect of it although I have done some extensive searching!

My question is: Why are parenthesis used in the middle of a method call?

```
    package com.zetcode;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


    public class QuitButtonExample extends JFrame {

    public QuitButtonExample() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       getContentPane().add(panel);

       panel.setLayout(null);

       JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
       quitButton.setBounds(50, 60, 80, 30);

       quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               System.exit(0);
          }
       });

       panel.add(quitButton);

       setTitle("Quit button");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                QuitButtonExample ex = new QuitButtonExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am referring to `getContentPane().add(panel);` statement.  I know what it does, but doesn't really understand how it works.  I'm new to Java and have the basics in OO like class fields, class methods, instance fields, instance methods, inner classes, but this one.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is: If a method returns an object then that object's methods can be called from that method.

Comment: Probably you would understand `{ Foo a = getFoo(); a.doSomethingFooish();}`. But there is no need to store the result of `getFoo()`, we can use it directly: `getFoo().doSomethingFooish()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what the common idiom, called *method chaining*, looks like.

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

parses as

```
Container c = this.getContentPane();
c.add(panel);
```

The parens indicate a method call, and its return value is used in-place as the `this` object for the next method call (`add`).

Answer (score 2):

This is called method chaining. To understand this a simple example will help you.

```
String a = "hellloo";
String b = a.toUpperCase().replace("LOO", "O").concat(" WORLD");    
System.out.println(b);
```

This is going to print HELLO WORLD.

Remember the methods in method chaining are processed from left to right.

Above it executes as

1. `toUpperCase()` - "HELLLOO"
2. `replace("LOO", "O")` - "HELLO"
3. `concat(" WORLD")` - "HELLO WORLD"
4. Assigns "HELLO WORLD" to string b.

Similarly for the above code we first get the ContentPane and then add a panel to it.

This reduces the amount of code required to achieve it.

Normally it would be like

```
Container container = getContentPane();
container.getContentPane();
```

Chaining reduces the code in half.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Method chaining, I come to think that I'm not new to it.  When I studied the "code", it didn't made sense.  Now I know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`getContentPane()` is a method being invoked on `this`.  Since it is a method it must be invoked using parenthesis.

In Java, `this` refers to the current instance of an object and can be omitted when calling methods in the current class.  Since `QuitButtonExample` extends the `JFrame` class it is able to call all protected and public methods of `JFrame`.

So you may not see the `getContentPane()` method on the class you are working on, but the method is available further up the class hierarchy and is exposed through the inheritance relationship with `JFrame`.

Also, the `getContentPane()` method returns an object of type `Container`, which we may also invoke methods upon.  When an object is received from a method and another method is instantly invoked such as `getContentPane().add(panel)` this is known as chaining.  It is not necessary to store each object returned from a method to a variable, we can simply use the object returned from the invoked method without assigning it to a stored variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

The `getContentPane` method has no input parameters, so you have to call it with empty parenthesis to make java compiler happy. After that you make a `add(panel)` call on the result of `getContentPane`-call.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification may be a bit formal, but as a developer, you are going to deal with a lot of formal grammars, so let me point out the relevant rules and interpret them:

The syntax of a [method invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) defines that parentheses are mandatory:

```
MethodInvocation:
    MethodName ( ArgumentList? )
    Primary . NonWildTypeArguments? Identifier ( ArgumentList? )
    ...
```

A [`Primary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) expression can be a `MethodInvocation`, so method invocations returning objects can be "chained":

```
Primary:
    PrimaryNoNewArray
    ...

PrimaryNoNewArray:
    ...
    MethodInvocation
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`getContentPane()` is a method in `JFrame` and returns an object (a `ContentPane`), which has a method `add()`, which in turn takes a ref to a `JPanel` object as its parameter. Pretty straight forward in the end.

Since `getContentPane()` belongs to the current object, it would be a bit clearer if the code were written as

```
this.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

To follow up on things like this it is a good idea to look in the Javadoc. e.g. 
[API for JSE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)