# Is chaining method calls to constructors a good practice in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have always thought that I have to initialize a class, before I can call it's non-static method, however, I came across a solution which had a method like this in it:

```
public String someStringMethod(){
    return new MyClass().toString();
}
```

So I may be new in development, but is it a good practice? Is this a better way to call a method than the "classic" (see below) way?

```
public String classicStringMethod(){
    MyClass cl = new MyClass();
    return cl.toString();
}
```

Do they have any performance difference? Does the first way has a "special name"?

Comment: *Do they have any performance difference? Does the first way has a "special name"?* **No.** They are equivalent. It doesn't have a special name that I'm aware of, beyond saving the reference to a local variable (or not).

Comment: Both ways achieve the exact same result. This is really just a stylistic difference. I prefer the second style. Feel it is a little more clear to the person coming after me or the poor person looking at it while they are tearing their hair out late at night trying to debug. Generally the compiler/optimizer is going to resolve this to same bytecode.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it's clear now.

Comment: Related to your example, but not the same thing, there is something called fluid interfaces - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java - in order to be able to chain operations together, a developer return an instance of the current object instead of void.

Comment: Oops, I'm sure chaos meant to type “fluent” where you see the word “fluid” in comment above.

Comment: The title of your question asked a slightly different question than the body. To answer the question posed in the title, _Why is throwing away the reference to a new instance valid in Java?_ the short answer is: [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). It's perfectly valid to create an object, do something with it (or even do nothing with it), then never reference it again. The VM will clean it up.

Comment: Down-voters: This is a valid question, one that certainly crossed my mind as a newbie. Please leave a specific criticism along with your vote if you feel compelled to down-vote.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title, moderators have edited it, I don't even know why, I gave a totally different title ("How is this valid in Java?").

Comment: @BasilBourque I suppose the downvotes are because there's little actual research effort on OP's part here - if he's more concerned with performance, he should a) check the bytecodes of both codes, b) profile them. If he's more concerned with coding style, then, as already pointed out, it's mildly arguable which form is better and when. Also, this is actually language agnostic - both (e.g.) C#, C++ and, AFAIK, any real object-oriented language (be it D or Objective Pascal) has the exactly same construct. As such, the question itself, as it's currently formulated, is IMO not a valuable one.

Comment: @BasilBourque also, OP obviously sees c-tor as something "magical" vs a regular method call... well, c-tor *is* somewhat magical under-the-hood, but as far as syntax goes, it's just a method. As such, he missed the fact that there ain't any special difference between `new Foo( new Bar() ).frong( new Baz() ).brong()` and, e.g. `newfooize( newbarize() ).frong( newbazize() ).brong()` ...

Comment: also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403054/why-are-parenthesis-used-in-the-middle-of-a-method-call-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No significant difference

As the comments explained, both approaches are semantically the same; both ways achieve the exact same result and the choice is really just a stylistic difference.

The second approach assigns the new object to a reference variable. The first approach skips the use of a reference variable. But in both cases the class was used as a definition for instantiating an object, and then the `toString` method was called on that object.

Semantically, first (chained/fluent) syntax usually informs you that the created object will be used only for a single chain of operations, and discarded afterwards. Since there's no explicit reference exported, it also signals that the scope of life of the object is limited to that very statement. The second (explicit) one hints that the object is/was/will be used for additional operations, be it another method calls, setting a field to it, returning it, or even just debugging. Still, [the general notion of using (or not) temporary helper variables is just a stylistic one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167777/why-should-one-use-a-single-use-temporary-variable).

Keep in mind that the variable is not the object. For example, the line `Dog hershey = new Dog( "Australian Shepard" , "red", "Hershey" );` uses *two* chunks of memory. In one chunk is the new object, holding the state data for the breed and color and name. In the other *separate* chunk is the reference variable `hershey` holding a pointer to the memory location of the memory chunk of the Dog object. The reference variable lets us later refer to the object.

Java syntax makes this jump from reference variable to object so seamlessly that we usually think of `hershey` *as* the `Dog` object “Hershey”, but in fact they are separate and distinct.

As for performance, any difference would be insignificant. Indeed, the compiler or JVM may well collapse the second approach’s two lines into the first approach‘s single line. I don't know for sure, and I don't really care. Neither should you. Our job is to write clear readable code. The job of the compiler and JVM is to run that code reliably, efficiently, and fast. Attempting micro-optimizations has been shown many times to be futile (or even counter-productive) as the JVM implementations are *extremely* sophisticated pieces of software engineering, highly-tuned for making such optimizations. You can best assist the compilers and JVMs by writing simple straight-forward code without “cleverness”.

Note that the second approach can make debugging easier, because your debugger can inspect the instantiated object by accessing the object via the reference variable, and because you can set a line breakpoint on that particular constructor call explicitly.

Comment: @vaxquis I agree with you. But practically speaking, the debugging need wins out. Seems like every time I skip the helper variable I end up regretting it, and have to go back to editing my source to add the extra line, because of needing to examine it in the debugger. I am speaking of writing my own lousy code. I am so used to this rewrite-to-enable-debugging that I the implication the reference will be reused (as you said) has been drummed out of my head. For well-debugged code, especially when aimed at wider population of programmers such as public open source, then your advice is sage.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess I'm still in a newbie era, where I'm trying to apply everything I've learned in school, exactly as I have learned it. I guess I'll stay with the helper variable method for debugging purposes, just as you have mentioned.

Comment: @vaxquis  We agree. This is a good exchange to have on record.

Comment: @BasilBourque In that case, I've taken the liberty to rephrase your answer a little; I've also incorporated the quote from `muglio` you referred to, since comment references are extremely prone to comment rot (e.g. user renames etc.), and mentioned how 2nd solution allows easy c-tor line breakpoints. Of course, feel free to revert the edit if you disagree with it.